# Src folder is not created while create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

While creating the react-app by = " npm create-react-app  "
src and public folder are not created

I tried:

1. npx craete-raect-app
2. npm rm -g create-react-app,
   npm install -g create-react-app,
   npx create-react-app .
3. npx --ignore-existing create-react-app Your-AppName

i tried these all but failed to create the src folder.

Comment: Does any one giving error? `npx create-react-app`

Comment: Does anything get created at all?

Comment: no ..by writing these  all command src folder is not created and not showing any error

Comment: Hi @NavreetKaur I am facing the same issue. I have uninstalled node and reinstalled it again twice but still no avail. Same with create-react-app. I could not find any solution here or anywhere else. How did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run this command `npx craete-raect-app app-name`

Comment: Yes I run this command still not generating the src folder

Comment: Do you get any error after running the above command?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, but after writing this command it seems nothing was working for a long time

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of what your command window looks after running `npx create-react-app testapp` ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether you have node installed on your machine:
Run this command:

```
node -v
```

It will show your node version if installed.

Next step you are not even creating an app. Give it a name `app-name`

```
npx create-react-app  app-name
```

This will create your app with src and public folder inside it.
Go to your app by:

```
cd app-name
npm start
```

Comment: Yes I run this command still not generating  the src folder

Comment: npm init react-app app-name
Or do it with yarn
yarn create-react-app app-name